Integration testing FMX app, page_source doesn't contain app controls
I'm exploring the idea of creating integrations tests for my FMX app. Ideally I'd be able to execute these tests for multiple platforms (Windows, Android, iOS, macOS), but for now I'm just trying to get it to work on Windows (64-bit) first using WinAppDriver.
I've created this Python script
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

os.startfile('C:\\Program Files\\Windows Application Driver\\WinAppDriver.exe')

desired_caps = {
    'app': "E:\\appiumtest\\integrationtestdemoproj.exe",
    'platformName': "Windows",
    'deviceName': "WindowsPC"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723", desired_caps)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

print(driver.page_source)

This is the printed driver.page_source
</?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Window AcceleratorKey="" AccessKey="" AutomationId="" 
ClassName="TFMAppClass" FrameworkId="Win32" HasKeyboardFocus="False" 
HelpText="" IsContentElement="True" IsControlElement="True" 
IsEnabled="True" IsKeyboardFocusable="True" IsOffscreen="True" 
IsPassword="False" IsRequiredForForm="False" ItemStatus="" ItemType="" 
LocalizedControlType="window" Name="Form1" Orientation="None" 
ProcessId="5040" RuntimeId="42.330834" x="0" y="0" width="0" 
height="0" CanMaximize="False" CanMinimize="True" IsModal="False" 
WindowVisualState="Normal" 
WindowInteractionState="ReadyForUserInteraction" IsTopmost="False" IsAvailable="True" //>

I've added a couple random characters to the xml output, because I couldn't get stackoverflow to display it well otherwise.
The problem with this output is that my test application executable contains a TButton and a TEdit, but they don't seem to show up in the output.
What I also find weird about the output is that FrameworkId is Win32 even though the application is 64-bit.
I looked up if I maybe need to add some accessibility info somehow. Based on this:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/FireMonkey_Accessibility_Package it seems like that's not the case.
I also find it interesting it is able to find the form and the its name, but not the controls.
Relevant version info

Windows 11
Delphi 12
Appium-Python-Client 1.3.0
selenium 3.141.0

I also tried a vcl app, same result. But if I try the calculator Windows calculator app for example it does work, I can see all the controls in the page_source.
Do fmx and vcl apps just not support what I'm trying to do? Couldn't find anywhere that it doesn't.
I'm interested if somebody else has tried something like this before and if there some way to make this work.

Win32 means Win32 API not the application bitness https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ Have you tried with the VCL application? VCL uses Win32 API controls and they should be recognized. FireMonkey uses custom drawn controls that don't have window handle attached, so they will not be picked up as controls, only main form window will. You might be able to get some of the controls if you switch their ControlType  property from Styled to Platform.

@DalijaPrasnikar Ah I see, that’s too bad. I did try VCL but got the same problem. But I’ll give it another try keeping your suggestions in mind. Thank you!

It is strange that it does not work for VCL application. Maybe it picks the wrong window handle.
